# How to get google form linked with google sheet using API in php. or Sheets linked with google form

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to get google form linked with **google sheet** using api in php. or Google sheet linked to form.

I have list of Google form using API and I want to get the Google sheet used to save responses of form. Or I have also list of google sheets is there way I can get form id linked with google sheet.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please add more deatils of what you have done.

Comment: I have list of Google form using API and I want to get the Google sheet used to save responses of form. Or I have also list of google sheets is there way I can get form id linked with google sheet.

Comment: You'll need to interact with Google Apps Script from your php backend. There's no other way to programmatically interact with Google Forms. Consult the Apps Script documentation to get started.

Comment: "_I have list of Google form using API_" @SanjivKumar Please show your php code.

Comment: @Tedinoz, here is my php code
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
 $drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
 $files_list = $drive->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles(); 

In $files_list I have array of all files present on google doc, 
I want to get form linked with google sheet  Like this form  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1waKk-p7sWWZeHfdY-ihm71ieD5pPz9jZPYNFaKPyhOg/  is linked with this google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uehLMNSaAN3R1SWJ735U02JpS1zhd3RbmHUsU-Co5Tc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

Run this in any spreadsheet and it will list each of the sheets and, if a sheet is linked to a form, it will list the url, ID and Title of the linked form.

---

```
  function LoopSheets4Forms(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheets = ss.getSheets();
      var numSheets = sheets.length
      if (numSheets > 1) {
        for (i=0;i<numSheets;i++){
          var sheetname = sheets[i].getName();
          Logger.log("DEBUG:i="+i+", Sheet name: "+ sheetname);//DEBUG
          var formURL =  sheets[i].getFormUrl();
          if(formURL != null){
            // not null
            Logger.log("DEBUG:Form url:"+formURL);//DEBUG
            var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
            Logger.log("DEBUG:Form title: "+form.getTitle());//DEBUG
            var formId = form.getId();
            Logger.log("DEBUG:Form id: "+ formId );//DEBUG
          }
          else
          {
            // is null
            Logger.log("DEBUG: this sheet not linked to a form");//DEBUG
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Using Apps Script its possible, But I was looking the way in PHP script.

Comment: Sorry, must have misunderstood the title "... or Sheets linked with google form"